# How to design a parents evening scheduling algorithm

Tags: python, scheduling

I am working on a project to create a school parents evening booking system. This system needs to be able to generate the best order of appointments based on availability of teachers and the priority given from parents.

Parents will be given the option to select which teachers they would like to see, then rank these choices from 1 (most important) to x(least important). They can also then enter the time they are at the event to and from.

Every parent will be given the opportunity to do this and once the booking system closes, an algorithm needs to work out how to allocate the slots based on this criteria for all parents. Additional choices which cannot fit and have a lower ranking can be discarded, but the higher ranked choices must be prioritised.

Each slot will be 10 minutes long and parents cannot have back to back appointments.

Any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 2):

These kinds of problems (scheduling) can very quickly become [non-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)), in which case you can't have a generic solution, you must simplify the problem itself. (Unless you want to get into the hardcore mathematics of non-linear optimization or discrete optimization).

Anyway, if you are lucky, your problem might be a [linear optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). In these kinds of problems, you have a bunch of constraints (like which parents are available when), and then you must have a single target function, which specifies what your optimum solution would look like. For example using the priorities of the parents-teachers as "weights".

The cool thing about this, is that there is a known algorithm that can optimally solve the problem called the [Simplex Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).